# Not able to put back picture in picture content to its original size

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, picture-in-picture

I have a button which presents `AVPlayerViewController` and i managed to add picture in pciture to my AVPlayerViewController so i can minimize it, now once minimized i want to maximize it again but as soon as i do it the `AVPlayerViewController` disappears. I don't plan to use storyboard and want to do it programmatically as embeding my view controller in navigation controller resolves the issue but i don't want to follow that approach

I added `BackgroundMode` capability and ticked `PIP` and in Appdelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(.playback)
            try audioSession.setActive(true, options: [])
        } catch {
            print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
        }
        
        return true
    }
```

and in my `ViewController`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {
    
    var playerController : AVPlayerViewController!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {


        if let videoURL = URL(string: "https://storage.googleapis.com/exoplayer-test-media-0/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4") {
            let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
            
            playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
            
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.didfinishPlaying(note:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
            
            playerController.player = player
            
            playerController.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true
            
            playerController.delegate = self
            
            playerController.player?.play()
            
            self.present(playerController, animated: true, completion : nil)
            
        }
    }
    
    
  
    
}
```

Just for creating a simple demo i used `storyboard`, in my real app i don't use it

Comment: if you want to use **picture in pciture** functions, you must be define `AVPictureInPictureController ` as embeding my view controller.

Comment: @M_JSL can you share code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController,AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {
    
    let playerController  = AVPlayerViewController()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        playerController.delegate = self
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        
        
        if let videoURL = URL(string: "https://storage.googleapis.com/exoplayer-test-media-0/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4") {
            let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
            
            playerController.player = player
            
            playerController.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true
            
            playerController.delegate = self
            
            playerController.player?.play()
            
            self.present(playerController, animated: true, completion : nil)
            
        }
    }
    
    func playerViewController(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            completionHandler(true)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

The above code works without `NavigationController`